# How to refresh the list of items after deleting one item using AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am a new to AngularJS area and I am trying to use it with ASP.NET Web API. I am struggling right now with the Delete Function. The user should be able to delete an item from a list of items and when he deletes an item successfully, the list should be updated (or refreshed) immediately after that deletion. I already implemented the deletion function, however, the list doesn't get updated after the deletion and I don't know why.

Here's the code of deletion function in Web API:

```
// DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            itemRepository.DeleteItem(id);
        }
```

And here's the AngularJS Controller Code:

```
app.controller('itemsController', ['itemsFactory', 'itemFactory', function (itemsFactory, itemFactory) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.message = "Welcome to Items Page";

        vm.Items= itemsFactory.query();

        // callback for ng-click 'deleteItem':
        vm.deleteItem = function (aId) {
            itemFactory.delete({ id: aId });
            vm.Items= itemsFactory.query();
        };
}]);
```

And here's the AngularJS Service Code:

```
app.factory('itemsFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/items', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    })
}); 

app.factory('itemFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/items/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET' },
        update: { method: 'PUT', params: { id: '@id' } },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: { id: '@id' } }
    })
});
```

**So how can I get the list of items updated immediately after any successful deletion operation?**

Answer (score 1):

That's because itemFactory.delete in your case is $resource object which run asynchronously. So the problem is in this rows:

```
// callback for ng-click 'deleteItem':
vm.deleteItem = function (aId) {

    // You send request to the server
    itemFactory.delete({ id: aId });

    // You don't get response from the server yet, so your item hasn't deleted.
    vm.Items= itemsFactory.query();
};
```

So to accomplish that all you need is update your vm.Items inside `itemFactory.delete` callback like this:

```
vm.deleteItem = function (aId) {
    itemFactory.delete({ id: aId }, function () {
        // Update your items after you get success response from the server after deleting
        vm.Items= itemsFactory.query();
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I would appreciate if you could help me and tell me how to update the list of items after getting success response from the server after deletion.