# How to display the returned refreshed list of items after deletion in AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am learning AngularJS and how to use it with ASP.NET Web API, and I am struggling right now with displaying the returned refreshed list of products after deleting one product by the manager. When he deletes a product successfully, the list of products will be updated immediately after that deletion. 
The deletion function works well, but after doing the deletion, I got the following error message:

[image]

I tried to follow the answer mentioned in this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291116/how-to-refresh-the-list-of-items-after-deleting-one-item-using-angularjs/30291184#30291184), but it seems that the developer returns a status from the deletion function in the Web API which is totally different than my case.

Here's the code of ProductRepository class:

```
public List<T_Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            var query = from product in db.T_Product
                        select product ;
            return query.ToList();
        }

public List<T_Product> DeleteProduct(int productId)
        {
            var pro = (from product in db.T_Product
                       where product .ProductId == productId
                       select product ).SingleOrDefault();
            db.T_Product.DeleteObject(pro);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return GetAllProducts();
        }
```

Here's the code of deletion function in Web API:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
        {
            var products = productRepository.DeleteProduct(id);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, products);
            return response;
        }
```

And here the AngularJS Controller Code:

```
app.controller('productsController', [productsFactory', 'productFactory', function (productsFactory, productFactory) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.Products = productsFactory.query();

        // callback for ng-click 'deleteProduct':
        vm.deleteProduct = function (aId) {
            productFactory.delete({ id: aId });
            vm.Products = productsFactory.query();
        };
}]);
```

And here's the AngularJS Service Code:

```
app.factory('productsFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/products', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    })
});

app.factory('productFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/products/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET' },
        update: { method: 'PUT', params: { id: '@id' } },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: { id: '@id' } }
    })
});
```

I debugged and captured the network packet using F12 in the IE 9 and the code returns the updated list but it did not show in the page. **Why?**

**So how can I display the returned updated list of products immediately after any successful deletion operation?**

Comment: Not an answer but I think you'd be better just returning a status code from the Delete action and onsuccess you can simply remove the item from the client side model. (sorry if I'm missing something)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the problem is exactly the same as the question you linked. `productFactory.delete({ id: aId });` is an asynchronous call, so it needs time to send data to the server and get data back. You should put the code you want to happen after the delete occurs inside the delete's callback function:

```
// callback for ng-click 'deleteProduct':
vm.deleteProduct = function (aId) {
    productFactory.delete({ id: aId }, function() {
        vm.Products = productsFactory.query();
    });
};
```

This way you can be sure the query function will happen after the item is deleted on the server.

Ideally you shouldn't need to call `.query()` again, and would just delete the item locally. That way you wouldn't need to wait for another server request/response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be setting the value of vm.Products in a callback - Angular is resolving the asynchronous value initially (so simply assigning productsFactory.query directly to the vm.Products does work when the controller is created, as all async operations are completed before rendering), but when it comes to refreshing it after delete that doesn't work - translating your code so it is all callback-happy:

```
app.controller('productsController', [productsFactory', 'productFactory', function (productsFactory, productFactory) {
    var vm = this;

    productsFactory.query(function (products) {
        vm.Products = products;
    });

    // callback for ng-click 'deleteProduct':
    vm.deleteProduct = function (aId) {
        productFactory.delete({ id: aId }, function() {
            productsFactory.query(function (products) {
                vm.Products = products;
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the resource to accept an array response

```
delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: { id: '@id' }, isArray: true }
```

and either using the value from the callback

```
vm.deleteProduct = function (aId) {
    productFactory.delete({ id: aId }, function(remainingProducts) {
        vm.Products = remainingProducts;
    });
};
```

or the promise from the resource method

```
vm.deleteProduct = function (aId) {
    vm.Products = productFactory.delete({ id: aId });
};
```

should do the trick.

As others have mentioned, you would typically just delete the item locally once the delete call returns (that is, inside the callback). What I tend to do is removing the item instantly and then re-add it if something goes wrong (by providing a second error-callback). Keep in mind though that the list might have changed in the meantine (unless the UI is somehow 'locked' during the AJAX call).

As a side note: the `productFactory` is also concerned with product**s**, so you might want to consider merging the two resources. Having an empty or no `id` will go to just the right server resource.